# Ruby "Colorful Number" method for numbers with only three digits - absolute beginner -

Tags: ruby

I'm an absolute coding beginner and have just started to learn ruby. I had a challenge where I was supposed to check if a number was "colorful".

When in a given number, product of every digit of a sub-sequence are different. That number is called Colorful Number.

For example, "263 is a colorful number because [2, 6, 3, 2*6, 6*3, 2*6*3] are all different; whereas 236 is not colorful, because [2, 3, 6, 2*3, 3*6, 2*3*6] have 6 twice.

So take all consecutive subsets of digits, take their product and ensure all the products are different."

In the challenge given we were to only accept numbers up to three digits.

So since I am a beginner I tried to write every product seperately.
I know this is not "good" code, but still I want to understand why it is not working. I think it should... but it doesn't :)

I would be so glad if someone could tell my why this is not working.
I am not looking for a nicer solution, I really just want to know why mine doesn't work.

THANK YOU SO MUCH!

```
def colorful?(number)
  if number.class != Integer
    return false
  elsif number.to_s.length > 3
    return false
  elsif number == 0 || 1
    return true
  end

  digits_arr = number.digits.reverse
  product_1 = digits_arr[0]*digits_arr[1]
  product_2 = digits_arr[1]*digits_arr[2]
  product_3 = digits_arr[0]*digits_arr[1]*digits_arr[2]

  final_array = digits_arr + product_1 + product_2 + product_3

  if final_array.uniq.length == final_array.length
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: I found a precise definition of a "colorful number" [here](https://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/colorful-numbers/).

Comment: This question was initially confusing because `[2, 6, 3, 2*6, 6*3, 2*6*3]` was written without escaping the asterisks, so it appeared as `[2, 6, 3, 26, 63, 263]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your biggest issue is here:

```
elsif number == 0 || 1
```

This means "when number is equal to 0 OR when 1 is truthy value". In Ruby, `1` is always a truthy value, so this condition is always satisfied, leading to the execution of `return true`, terminating your method and returning `true` for any value.

Once you replace it with either

```
elsif number == 0 || number == 1
```

or

```
elsif [0,1].include? number
```

you will still have some more issues to fix - next one will be `No implicit conversion of Integer into an Array` when you try to add number to an Array. I hope you'll figure this one out by yourself. :)

### While we're here, few minor notes.

In Ruby, we prefer duck-typing over strong types (mostly becuase we don't have strong typing) so any form of argument type checks like `if number.class != Integer` is thrown upon (not to mention it won't work very well as you will reject a large number of other `Numeric` classes - if you have to chack for classes use `is_a?` or `kind_of?`). Note that if your method is ever executed with something that is not a number, you do want to throw an exception rather than let the calculation continue - it is much easier to prevent your system from getting into a bad state than debugging the bad state and guessing how you got there.

Might be personal opinion here, but `elsif` sucks - almost always there is a better way. In this scenario, since you're returning in each case, you could just do:

```
return false unless number.is_a? Integer # really unnecessary
return false if number.to_s.length > 3
return true if number == 0 || number == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'set'

def colorful?(n)
  digits = n.digits.reverse
  products = Set.new
  (1..digits.size-1).each do |n|
    digits.each_cons(n) { |a| return false unless products.add?(a.reduce(:*)) }
  end
  true
end
```

```
colorful? 263
  #=> true
```

```
colorful? 236
  #=> false
```

```
colorful? 3245
  #=> true
```

See [Set#add?](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add-3F)

---

I can best show how the method works by adding some `puts` statements and executing the method for two of the example integers above.

```
def colorful?(n)
  digits = n.digits.reverse
  puts "digits = #{digits}"
  products = Set.new
  (1..digits.size-1).each do |n|
    puts "n = #{n}"
    puts "digits.each_cons(#{n}).to_a #=> #{digits.each_cons(n).to_a}"
    digits.each_cons(n) do |a|
      m = a.reduce(:*)
      puts "  a = #{a}, m = #{m}"
      puts "  products = #{products}"
      puts "  products.include?(#{m}) = #{products.include?(m)}"
      return false unless products.add?(m)
    end
  end
  puts "true is returned"
  true
end
```

---

```
colorful? 263
  #=> true
```

The following is displayed.

```
digits = [2, 6, 3]
n = 1
digits.each_cons(1).to_a #=> [[2], [6], [3]]
  a = [2], m = 2
  products = #<Set: {}>
  products.include?(2) = false
  a = [6], m = 6
  products = #<Set: {2}>
  products.include?(6) = false
  a = [3], m = 3
  products = #<Set: {2, 6}>
  products.include?(3) = false
n = 2
digits.each_cons(2).to_a #=> [[2, 6], [6, 3]]
  a = [2, 6], m = 12
  products = #<Set: {2, 6, 3}>
  products.include?(12) = false
  a = [6, 3], m = 18
  products = #<Set: {2, 6, 3, 12}>
  products.include?(18) = false
true is returned
```

---

```
colorful? 236
  #=> false
```

The following is displayed.

```
digits = [2, 3, 6]
n = 1
digits.each_cons(1).to_a #=> [[2], [3], [6]]
  a = [2], m = 2
  products = #<Set: {}>
  products.include?(2) = false
  a = [3], m = 3
  products = #<Set: {2}>
  products.include?(3) = false
  a = [6], m = 6
  products = #<Set: {2, 3}>
  products.include?(6) = false
n = 2
digits.each_cons(2).to_a #=> [[2, 3], [3, 6]]
  a = [2, 3], m = 6
  products = #<Set: {2, 3, 6}>
  products.include?(6) = true
```

Because `products` was found to contain `m` (`3`), `false` was returned.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I've solved it like this (I know there are nicer ways, but still, it now works (as in can tell if a number is colorful or not, if it has no more than 3 digits):

```
def colorful?(number)
  return false unless number.is_a? Integer

  digits_arr = number.digits.reverse

  return false if digits_arr.length > 3

  return true if digits_arr.length == 1

  final_array = []
  final_array << digits_arr

  case digits_arr.length
  when 3
    product_one = digits_arr[0] * digits_arr[1]
    final_array << product_one
    product_two = digits_arr[1] * digits_arr[2]
    final_array << product_two
    product_three = digits_arr[0] * digits_arr[1] * digits_arr[2]
    final_array << product_three
  when 2
    product_one = digits_arr[0] * digits_arr[1]
    final_array << product_one
  end

  if final_array.flatten.uniq == final_array.flatten
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def colorful?(number)
  return false unless number.is_a? Integer
  return false if number == 10
  digits_a = number.digits.reverse
  return false if digits_a.size > 3
  return true if number == 0 || number == 1 || digits_a.size < 3

  products = []
  digits_a.each_index do |i|
    digits_a.each_index do |j|
      next if i > j
      product = digits_a[i..j].reduce(:*)
      return false if products.include?(product)
      products << product
    end
  end

  true
end
```

So this code worked for me. I am a beginner coder as well hehe, just finished the coding bootcamp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).